# Downgrade to previous Linux kernel or libc6 version on OpenVZ (libc6 issue)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, upgrade, libc6

Recently i've tried to upgrade my server OS from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.10, then i've found out that i'm on OpenVZ virtualization and it's impossible and stuck in the middle.
Now apt-get install/update/upgrade doesn't works, screaming about installing new kernel and unmet dependencies with libc6, disk space garbaged to 99%, and i'm in panic

How can i revert or downgrade this stucked update?

```
#lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

[screaming about kernel on apt-get -f install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaEV6.png)

```
#dpkg -l |grep linux
ii  console-setup-linux                 1.108ubuntu15.5                              all          Linux specific part of console-setup
ii  libselinux1:amd64                   2.4-3build2                                  amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  linux-base                          4.5ubuntu1~16.04.1                           all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-headers-4.11.2-041102         4.11.2-041102.201705201036                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.11.2
ii  linux-headers-4.11.2-041102-generic 4.11.2-041102.201705201036                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.11.2 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.11.2-041102-generic   4.11.2-041102.201705201036                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.11.2 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                4.4.0-154.181                                amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  util-linux                          2.27.1-6ubuntu3.7                            amd64        miscellaneous system utilities

#apt-get install sl 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.27) but 2.23-0ubuntu11 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.23-0ubuntu11 is to be installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.27) but 2.23-0ubuntu11 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


#uname -r
2.6.32-042stab136.1
```

Comment: Downgrading packages isn't a supported operation.  I suggest you revert to the backup you took before you commenced the OS upgrade.

Comment: that's great, but i ain't got one

Comment: Then you have learnt a valuable operational lesson.  Two, if you include knowing what infrastructure you're using.